# How to fill in the Canada Express Entry Profile when I am married but separated and my spouse is not coming with me?

Tags: canada, legal, express-entry

I am completing my Express Entry profile. Under the "Creating your Profile" page, I have answered "Married" for Marital Status. Following this is the question: "Is your spouse/common-law partner included in this application?" I would like to answer "No" for the sole reason that we are already separated.

Regardless of the points, education, language etc, my husband and I are already separated. It is, however, a very unfortunate case that as having married in the Philippines, we can't file a divorce. Divorce is not legal in the Philippines. However, my ex-husband and I have decided to simply part ways.

In my case, it will be fraudulent to say "YES", because my husband is NEITHER included in my application, NOR would he want to be included in this application. But as I have read several feedbacks saying that the applicant should include the spouse, now I am utterly confused. I am not lying regarding my marital status. I am married by law. I am not lying about my application either.

He is not coming with me to Canada, or anywhere else for that matter. Why ask a question that states "Is your spouse included..." if the only answer for couples is "YES"?

Comment: My wife in the USA and myself in Canada ended up having to write *no* on similar forms about being married.

Comment: I keep hearing about this: http://www.international-divorce.com/d-dominican.htm

Comment: What's the issue? The second question is whether he wants to emigrate. Answer no.

Comment: You need to consider the reasons behind advice you've seen that an "applicant should include the spouse."  I expect that such advice is in response to people whose spouses intend to immigrate, and they are considering whether to bring the spouse later on a separate application.  Or perhaps there is some other reason that they are considering omitting the spouse, despite being in a functioning marriage.  In your case, your marriage is not functioning, and you do not intend ever to be with your husband in Canada, so it seems there is no reason to include him in your application.

Answer (score 3):

You're totally correct to answer honestly - NO, your spouse is not included on your application.

If in doubt, tell the truth, and if you're worried about their understanding, include a note / additional letter. I've done this for multiple applications (I've moved countries a bit).

I have colleagues and friends who moved overseas without their spouses for a year to work, even though they're married, and the spouse would not be joining them. It's perfectly common, and you're fully entitled to answer 'no' even if you're 'married' but separated - it doesn't matter - the application form is to cover those applying to enter.  You are, your spouse is not.

Good luck, and enjoy Canada - it's a beautiful country.